# Write gzipped Json objects into a Json file without loading it

Tags: python, json, list, file, dictionary

I want to write dicts as gzipped json objects into a json file.

I had some solutions, but as the file got bigger the appending process got slower and slower.
So loading the file was not the way.

I found the solution here with:

```
def append_record_seek(data,filename):
    print('append_record_seek started with data:{data} filename:{filename}')
    with open (filename, mode="r+") as file:
        file.seek(os.stat(filename).st_size -1)
        file.write( ",]".format(json.dumps(data)) )
```

Later i want to read that file as a list of dicts.

Here is my minimal Code example:

```
import global_variables as gv
import time
import json as json
import base64
import io
import sys
import cv2
import gzip

import numpy as np

import os

from numpy import asarray
from json import JSONEncoder




data = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}
path = r'C:/Videotool/Data'
name = 'test'
filename = path + '/' + name + '.json'
isExist = os.path.exists(path)
if not isExist:
    os.makedirs(path)
os.chdir(path)




def first_writer(data,filename):
    print(f'first_writer started with data:{data} filename:{filename}')
    with open (filename, 'w') as file:
        file.write('[')
        file.write(json.dumps(data))
        file.write(',')
        file.write(']')

        
def append_record_seek(data,filename):
    print('append_record_seek started with data:{data} filename:{filename}')
    with open (filename, mode="r+") as file:
        file.seek(os.stat(filename).st_size -1)
        file.write( ",]".format(json.dumps(data)) )




for x in range(6):
    print(f'step:{x}')
    file_exists = os.path.exists(name+'.json')
    if file_exists:
        print('file_exists')
        append_record_seek(data,filename)
    else:
        print('else')
        first_writer(data,filename)
```

the non zipped result should be looking like:

```
[{"brand": "Ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1964},
{"brand": "Ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1964},
{"brand": "Ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1964},
{"brand": "Ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1964},
{"brand": "Ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1964}]
```

My result is : `[{"brand": "Ford", "model": "Mustang", "year": 1964},,,,,,]`

If that works, i want to zip the dumps before writing.

I hope somebody can help

Update:
I've got the right Json format with:

```
def first_writer(data,filename):
    print(f'first_writer started with data:{data} filename:{filename}')
    with open (filename, 'w') as file:
        file.write( "[{}]".format(json.dumps(data)) )

        
def append_record_seek(data,filename):
    print('append_record_seek started with data:{data} filename:{filename}')
    with open (filename, mode="r+") as file:
        file.seek(os.stat(filename).st_size -1)
        file.write( ",{}]".format(json.dumps(data)) )
```

Now i have to get that zipped...

Comment: Quite sure this is not possible as  even `tarfile` doesnt allow append with compression.

Comment: It worked with -> with gzip.open(file, 'w') as fout:
                fout.write(json.dumps(sum_dict).encode('utf-8'))  
but i have to modify that for the append_record_seek() function. 
But first i have to get my List of Dicts as Json Object...

Comment: You can append as many gzipped blocks into single file but the result will not be valid json.  Content of the previously stored data needs to be mutated (eg, last `]` needs to be replaced to `,`.   GZIP format has crc-32 and original length of the compressed data  among other data and those would need to be re-calculated if you want to modify the data. Which would mean that you need to read the whole data before the algo can calculate the crc and length and what not..

Comment: I would go with loosing valid json, as long as i can read the gzipped blocks and put it back together in a list of dicts... valid json is not a requirement.

Comment: You will shoot yourself in the foot in the long run but i'll give an example in a "answer" ..

Comment: " So loading the file was not the way." it is the way. YOu should consider just using a JSON-lines format (a single JSON on each line). That way, you can just append to the file. Otherwise, there is no generic way to modify a JSON

Comment: "I would go with loosing valid json, as long as i can read the gzipped blocks and put it back together in a list of dicts... valid json is not a requirement" this is just confused. How do you expect to read it back in a list of dicts? Manually writing some parser for the messed up format you generate? No. Again, you should really just use newline delimited JSON format

Comment: I save cam images to that json file, besides other data. If i load the existing file to append data, the process takes longer and longer. I need to be as fast as possible. The second problem is the resulting size of that file. with my old version in gzip i reached 30Mb per Minute. So the best thing would be gzipped valid Json and a fast appending process. I am open to Ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: This is not the answer to the question, as there is none, this will just highlight that a single compressed file can be generated and decompressed later *but* it will **not** be valid json.

```py
import gzip
from copy import copy
import json

# just test data
x = {
  "brand": "Ford",
  "model": "Mustang",
  "year": 1964
}
z = {
  "brand": "Mato",
  "model": "Laatikko",
  "year": 2023
}

l = []

# populate the initial "json" in the list l
for i in range(3):
  y = copy(x)
  y["year"] += i
  l.append(y)

# write list of dicts as jsons string into file and compress it via gzip
# it doesnt really matter how this was originally done..
with open("data.gz", "wb") as f:
   f.write(gzip.compress(bytes(json.dumps(l, indent=2),"utf-8")))

# then, append a new entry to the same file -- which will get uncompressed
# with the previously stored *valid* json structure..

with open("data.gz", "ab") as f:
   f.write(gzip.compress(bytes(json.dumps(z, indent=2),"utf-8")))
```

This will result a file that looks like this when uncompressed

```
[
  {
    "brand": "Ford",
    "model": "Mustang",
    "year": 1964
  },
  {
    "brand": "Ford",
    "model": "Mustang",
    "year": 1965
  },
  {
    "brand": "Ford",
    "model": "Mustang",
    "year": 1966
  }
]{
  "brand": "Mato",
  "model": "Laatikko",
  "year": 2023
}
```

Comment: I wrote a read function that put everything back to json and lists. Thanks!